# Elementwise multiplication two matrices or PrimitiveDenseStores in ojAlgo

Tags: java, matrix, ojalgo

Can anyone tell me how to multiply corresponding elements of two matrices in ojAlgo?
Looking for block function for `c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j]`

Comment: Also can anyone with enough points create this tag "ojAlgo" for this high performance math library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Here's one alternative:

matrixA.operateOnMatching(MULTIPLY, matrixB).supplyTo(matrixC);

Where MULTIPLY comes from a static import (org.ojalgo.function.constant.PrimitiveMath).

Comment: Shouldn't `SUBTRACT` be `MULTIPLY` here?